# get nested collection data with child id only in Firestore

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 with Firestore and using AngularFire2

I have nested collection in the Firestore database

```
|- service_states                       # Collection
  | collection_id: 12345
  | name: Delhi
    |- service_cities                   # Collection
       | collection_id: 23456
       | name: Delhi
         |- service_area                # Collection
            | collection_id: 3456
            | name: Area 1
```

I have another independent collection

```
|- profile
   | user_id: 8765
   | service_area: 3456
```

I'm able to get the **service_area** details, If I have **service_states** and **service_cities** data like

```
this.profileCollection = this.aFS.collection('service_states/12345/service_cities/23456/service_ares/3456');
```

**But in this case, I don't have `service_area` id and `service_states` id.
How can I get the details of `service_area` with only `service_area` id?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't build the full path to a collection, including any necessary intermediate document IDs, then it's not possible to do anything with that collection.  You must be able to find a collection to query it.

If you don't know anything about a document except some value of a field contained in the document, you'll need to query a top-level collection to get it.  So, perhaps you need a new top-level collection to contain all the service areas.